# 1Password CLI (op): Cannot get the `--session` flag to work with any commands

Tags: command-line-interface, 1password

I cannot get the `--session` flag to work with [1Password CLI](https://developer.1password.com/docs/cli/) commands.

I use a valid session token.

#### Working Example

`op list items` without session flag works:

```bash
$ OP_SESSION_my=XXXXX-this-is-not-the-real-token-XXXXX op list items
[{"uuid": "asdfghj etc etc etc"
```

#### Failing Example

But `op list items` with session flag and same token as above  doesn't:

```bash
$ op list items --session XXXXX-this-is-not-the-real-token-XXXXX
[LOG] 2020/02/21 22:48:59 (ERROR)  Invalid session token
```

I can do anything I want with a valid session token:

- obtain it via `op signin --raw`
- assign it with `eval $(op signin etc)`

Every command works, but not when using the `--session` flag.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

On the 1Password CLI forums, I was told this was a known issue. As a workaround, `--session=YOUR_SESSION_TOKEN` does work. The docs do not specify the `=` but for now it works. E.g. `op list items --session=XXXXX-this-is-not-the-real-token-XXXXX`